# type object 'ProductForm' has no attribute 'cleaned_data' django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am making a form using Django 2.0.x  and Python 3.6  and I am getting an error

I'm not sure what's going on, can someone help me out? Thanks!

> Product/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title       = forms.CharField(label='',
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your title"}))
    description = forms.CharField(
                        required=False,                         
    widget=forms.Textarea())
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',

        ]
```

> Product/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from django.http import *
from .models import Product
from .forms import ProductForm
import hashlib

# Create your views here.

def home_view(request,slug,*args,**kwargs):
    form= ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    try:
        productobject=Product.objects.get(id=1)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    if form.is_valid():

        newProduct=Product.objects.create(
        title = "jose",

        description=ProductForm.cleaned_data.get["description"]


        )

        if newProduct:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/)

        else:
            newProduct = ProductForm()

context= {
        "sampletext": "text",
        "form": form,
        "productobject":productobject,

    }
    return render(request, "home.html",context)
```

The code is giving me this error

type object 'ProductForm' has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: It should be `form.cleaned_data`, and you should *only* call it after `form.is_valid()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch the `cleaned_data` from the `ProductForm` *class*, not from the `form` object that is an *instance* of `ProductForm`.

You can thus fix it by using `form` instead, like:

```
def home_view(request,slug,*args,**kwargs):
    form= ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    try:
        productobject=Product.objects.get(id=1)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    if form.is_valid():

        newProduct=Product.objects.create(
            title = "jose",
            description=form.cleaned_data.get["description"]
        )
        if newProduct:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            newProduct = ProductForm()
    context= {
        "sampletext": "text",
        "form": form,
        "productobject":productobject,

    }
    return render(request, "home.html",context)
```

But that being said, the workflow is not *idiomatic*. For example `if newProduct` will always succeed, regardless whether this is a valid `newProduct` or not. The `Product.objects.create(..)` however can raise an exception. A more idiomatic workflow is:

```
def home_view(request,slug,*args,**kwargs):
    try:
        productobject=Product.objects.get(id=1)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    if request.method = 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.title = "jose"
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')  # name of the view
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    context= {
        "sampletext": "text",
        "form": form,
        "productobject":productobject,

    }
    return render(request, "home.html",context)
```